# In Android monkeyrunner, is there anything similar to waitForPageToLoad()

Tags: android, selenium, monkeyrunner

In Android monkeyrunner, is there anything similar to waitForPageToLoad() (like in Selenium), as I don't want to use Thread.sleep() because of its limitations?

Answer (score 0):

Try [Robotium](http://code.google.com/p/robotium/), which is a test framework for Android apps.

Quote:
"Robotium is an Android test framework that has full support for Activities, Dialogs, Toasts, Menus and Context Menus. 
The project home page is at http://www.robotium.org/"

Robotium provides a set of APIs for waiting for an Activity/View etc. e.g.
`waitForActivity(String name)` and
`waitForView(Class<T> viewClass)`

Comment: Thanks Alex. In our project, I'm supposed to use MonkeyRunner only. I know that Robotium might be better than MonkeyRunner but it still is MonkeyRunner which I have to use and not Robotium.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure if MonkeyRunner could achieve this... BTW, what are the limitations of `MonkeyRunner.sleep()` you've metioned? Since you are executing a PC side script, you could just let it safely sleep for a pretty long time, thus you can avoid unpleasent things like racing conditions etc..